# Coordenadas do cursor do console em C

Tags: c, console, posição-do-cursor

Pegando o seguinte código como exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Onde o "Hello World" será escrito na linha 1 e na coluna 1 do console. Como eu faço para alterar isto, por exemplo, escreve-lo na linha 3, coluna 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe uma forma padrão de fazer isto, depende da biblioteca de console que está usando. No Linux costuma dar certo fazer isto:

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", x, y);
}
```

Em Windows pode usar o [`SetConsoleCursorPosition()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y) { 
    COORD pos = {x, y};
    HANDLE output = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(output, pos);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/Cursor.c).

Comment: Só pra adicionar, é necessário dar include em windows.h para poder usar esta função.

Comment: Funcionou, vlw :D